# I am not getting the image selected from gallery in my android live wallpaper after i restart my phone in android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, gallery, live-wallpaper

In my Android Live Wallpaper application,my canvas contains a drawable image at a particular position.Now i am selecting an image from gallery on a button click and i am drawing it by using canvas in place of the drawable image.Now in my live wallpaper,the drawable image is replaced by the selected image from the gallery.It is working fine all the time.But if i restart my phone,my first drawable image is displayed in the live wallpaper but not the image selected from gallery.I need the image selected from my gallery in my live wallpaper even if i restart the phone.I am very confused to do it.Please help me.I am providing code for image selection from gallery.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {    
    Uri contentUri = data.getData();

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String tmppath = cursor.getString(column_index);


    Bitmap croppedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmppath);

}
 }
```

I am writing the logic as "if the above cropped image is null then i am drawing drawable image on the canvas,otherwise i am drawing cropped image". After restarting my phone the cropped image always becomes null.so i am getting only drawable image in my live wallpaper.but i need the cropped image to be in my live wallpaper even after restarting the phone.please help me to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store that `tmppath` in SharedPreference and retrieve it as and when required.

Comment: thanks for the answer.How to retrieve it on restarting the phone

Comment: Retrieve values from sharedpreference in onCreate() and check the same. If there is a path stored then load it otherwise it will give you null.

Comment: I am storing the path,but i am getting null again.can u pls tell me ho to store it.